# BaseGameUtils Module Causing Runtime Exception

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I'm following the Google tutorial on "Accessing the Play Games Services APIs in Your Android Game". As part of the tutorial, I was instructed to add the BaseGameUtils module, but when I do, I get the following error during compilation:

Error:Execution failed for task ':BaseGameUtils:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library

Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

I tried this suggestion ^ and I tried implementing all the other solutions out there. I also tried to delete the module, redownload it and add it back.

Here is my build.gradle (Module:app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.matan.real"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}
```

And here is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.matan.real">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!